# Mass matrix second order differential equation to first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, jacobian

I want to simulate the behaviour of a 2-DOF robotic manipulator, which is described by the following model:

$$ M(q)\ddot{q} = -C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}-G(q)+\tau \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$

Considering the fact that the $\text{2x2}$ mass matrix $M$ is positive definite, I could use the inverse matrix and break down the problem into the $4$ first order ordinary differential equations and simulate it:

$$ x_1 = q_1 \Rightarrow \dot{x_1} = x_2 $$
$$ x_2 = \dot{q_1} \Rightarrow \dot{x_2} = -M^{-1}(1,:)\cdot C\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_2 & x_4 \end{bmatrix}^{T}-M^{-1}(1,:)\cdot G + M^{-1}(1,:)\cdot \tau $$
$$ x_3 = q_2 \Rightarrow \dot{x_3} = x_4 $$
$$ x_4 = \dot{q_2} \Rightarrow \dot{x_4} = -M^{-1}(2,:)\cdot C\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_2 & x_4 \end{bmatrix}^{T}-M^{-1}(2,:)\cdot G + M^{-1}(2,:)\cdot \tau $$

Suppose I would like to use a solver that takes as an argument the mass matrix (a MATLAB ODE solver in particular) and don't use its inverse because this will also simplify the computation of the jacobian (I intend to simulate a 7-DOF robotic manipulator after that so providing the mass matrix would be great). How can I write the initial equation $(1)$ as a series of first order ordinary differential equations and be able to simulate its response by using some software solvers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us choose $\eta = \begin{bmatrix} q & \dot{q} \end{bmatrix}^\top$. Then
$$\begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\ 0&M(q) \end{bmatrix}\dot{\eta} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ 0 & -C(q,\dot{q})\end{bmatrix}\eta + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -G(q) + \tau \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: And now which equations should I solve ? The ones on the right hand side and pass the mass matrix (on the left hand side) as an argument to the ODE solver ? Could you maybe expand it until the final first order ODEs that I should send to the solver ?

Comment: The equation in my answer is exactly the first-order ODE. Consider the example www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-equations-of-motion-for-baton.html.

Comment: Great thank you. You consider $η$ to be equal to $η=[q_1 \ q_2 \ \dot{q_1} \ \dot{q_2}]$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right concerning $\eta$